# Data from API: Retrieving specific data JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, get

I am a novice frontender and just started working with backend API There is this API: https://sportpro3.herokuapp.com/api/sports/Sports/ where there are fields: image, title, description, category_of_sports:category The question is as follows: Is it possible to get those data where category_of_sports:category for example: Olympic sports

If I request, all the data comes

I will be very happy for every answer!:)

```js
export const MainPart = () => {
  const [mainCards, setMainCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMain = async () => {
      const response = await axios
        .get("https://sportpro3.herokuapp.com/api/sports/Sports/")
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      console.log(response);
      setMainCards(response.data);
    };

    fetchMain();
  }, []);

  console.log(mainCards);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="main">
        <div className="main__container">
          
          <div className="main__title">Sports</div>
          <div className="sports__title">National Sports</div>
<div className="main__cards"></div>
          
          <MainComponent mainCards={mainCards} />
          <div className="sports__title">Olympia sports</div>
          <OlympicSport />
          <div className="sports__title">Nonolympia sports</div>
          <NotOlympicSport />
          <div className="sports__title">Para and Sourdough</div>
          <ParaSport />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

Main Component

function MainComponent({ mainCards }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {mainCards &&
        mainCards.map((mainCards) => (
          <MainInfo mainCards={mainCards} key={mainCards.id} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainComponent;

MainINfo


function MainInfo({ mainCards }) {
  return (
    <div className="main__info">
      <img src={mainCards.image} alt="" className="main__image"></img>
      <div className="main__container">
        <div className="main__up">
          <span className="main__author">{mainCards.title}</span> <br />
        </div>
        <h1 className="main_title">{mainCards.description}</h1>
        <p>{mainCards.category_of_sports.category}</p>
        <Link to={`/main/${mainCards.toString()}`}>Read more...</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainInfo;
```

Comment: You will have to create a specific route in your backend that only returns that what you want. Otherwise services like graphql are a good option for these kind of stuff. Otherwise process the data yourself.

Comment: [`filter` on that object property value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: As @Andy said you can filter the array of objects based on a particular sport, as per requiremrnt.

Answer (score 0):

```
const filteredData = data.filter((obj)=> obj.category_of_sports.category === 'Olympic');
```

filter() function creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. so we passed an arrow function where the obj parameter represents the object of the data array.

Comment: can you also provide some explanation

Comment: @saurabh filter() function creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. so we passed an arrow function where the obj parameter represents the object of the data array.
for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter